# Что означает данная запись в Python: tab_value = ["?" for i in range(n)]?

Tags: python, c#, массивы

Пытаюсь перенести программу с Python на C#. В объявлении массива есть такая запись:

```
tab_value = ["?" for i in range(n)]
```

Что означает "?" в данном случае?

Comment: заполняет list(массив) знаком вопроса tab_value =  ['?','?','?']

Comment: почитайте про списковые включения.

Comment: `var array = new string[n]; Array.Fill(array, "?");` или так `var array = Enumerable.Repeat("?", n).ToArray();`

Comment: Это тоже самое что и `["?"] * n`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Вместо знака вопроса можно поставить либо переменную либо другое слово или символ, это краткая запись, можно объявить массив и после с помощью цикла for заполнить его знаками "?"
По итогу массив заполниться так же как и при краткой записи